# JQuery: Selecting elements with unique class AND id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I have this html code:

```
<div class="category" id="154"> Category </div>

<div class="category2" id="156"> Category2 </div>

<div class="category3" id="157"> Category3 </div>

<div class="category4" id="158"> Category4 </div>
<input type="text" />
```

So in example if I write a id in text box, how to select div .category with this ID and get inner HTML text. With jQuery

Comment: To select the element with [`id=153`](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0123), you’ll have to use `#\31 23` in CSS, or `$('#\\31 23');` when using the JavaScript Selectors API (or implementations that make use of it, like jQuery). See [CSS character escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so you only need to use the ID as this is a unique value (or should be)

```
var html = $("#154").html();
```

**NOTE**: If you do have duplicate ID values in use then it is important to note that JQuery will only select the first one.

---

if you want to do this when a textbox value is entered you could do this on the textbox change event...

```
$("input").change(function(){
   var id = $(this).val();
   var element = $("#" + id);
   if(element){
      var html = element.html();
      //do something with html here
   }
});
```

**NOTE**: you may want to put an ID value on your textbox to ensure you get the correct control

---

Although I **strongly** suggest you find a way around using duplicate ID values, you could have a function like this to get the DIV you want...

```
function GetContent(className, id) {
    var result = null;
    var matchingDivs = $("." + className);
    matchingDivs.each(function(index) {
        var div = $(matchingDivs[index]);
        if (div.attr("id") == id) {
            result = div.html();
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

[Click here for working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JUHLh/)

Comment: but if I have other element with similar id, can i select element by class + ID?

Comment: @DonatasVeikutis: No, Jquery will not wotrk the way you want with duplicate ID values. You could use the name attribute instead if you must have duplicates. Something like... `$(".class [name=154]").html();`  - you could, if you must have duplicate ID's, loop each div in matching class and find the id (ill add something to the post for this)

Comment: @Donatas: Duplicate IDs are simply invalid in HTML. There are ways to achieve what you want but it would be better overall if you'd create valid HTML.

Comment: @DonatasVeikutis: Please try and use unique ID values, but if you really must duplicate them... see my edit for a function to help you out ;)

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to find an element by a particular class, and then get the ID of that element. This function (slightly altered) got the job done! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you give the textbox an ID, in case you add other textboxes to the page.

But if you only have the 1 text input, the following would work:

```
 var id = $('input:text:first').val();
 var innerHtml = $('#' + id).html();
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khh3k/) that will alert the html using this technique whenever the text in the textbox changes.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#id.class")`

will select the necessary element by both class and ID (replacing `id` and `class` with their respective names, of course).

Adding `.html()` to the end will get you the content.

i.e:
`$("#id.class").html()`

Comment: There should be no space between `#id` and `.class`. Otherwise it will find a *descendant* with class `class` of the element with ID `id`.